# How to determine what creates nonsensical characters

Tags: character-encoding, character, ascii

I am trying to determine what is causing this error:

```
  Transaction Error!
  There was a problem with the transaction. 
  The credit card information was initially accepted but an auto void has been placed because of a system error. 

  Please contact the association. 

  The site administrator has been notified of the error.
  The value u^m cannot be converted to a number.
```

This is happening during the processing of credit card payments.

Is there a way to know what translates to u^m or vice versa?  For instance %20 translates to a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be a value from a cookie, that had been encrypted on its way into the cookie, being translated as u^m because it was not decrypted when it was used to create an number.